# Reading a XML file from SQL Server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

An XML file was saved into a SQL Server database with the following code:

```
USE XML
GO

INSERT ENTERTAINMENT (content)
SELECT * FROM
    OPENROWSET(bulk 'c:\entertainment-jist.xml', single_blob ) AS X
```

The file was saved in a column with an `xml` datatype.

How can the whole content of this file be read in an asp.net page using C#?

Comment: Your caps lock is on. (We've edited the caps out, but your caps lock might still be on.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SqlDataReader.GetSqlXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlxml.aspx) to read the XML field.